# Get pyinstaller to error out on missing module, instead of creating a dependency on the runtime env

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyinstaller

I'm building a Python program into an executable using `pyinstaller`. I have two virtualenvs in my system:

Virtualenv `A`, which contains `pyinstaller`, `foo`, and so on. I run pyinstaller in this virtualenv as `pyinstaller --clean -y --log-level WARN myprogram.spec`.

Virtualenv `B`, which contains nothing. I run the resulting executable in this virtualenv.

Unfortunately, if my program looks like this:

```
import foo
import bar
```

then what I'm observing is that pyinstaller will correctly package up module `foo` (which is available in virtualenv `A`), and then leave the second import statement as a runtime import.

When I run the resulting program in virtualenv `B`, it crashes with an uncaught `ImportError`!

The crash-with-`ImportError` symptom makes sense to me, given the behavior of pyinstaller. But it's not very *friendly*. The behavior I really want is for pyinstaller itself to detect (during compilation) that module `bar` is not installed in virtualenv `A`, and thus cannot be packaged up, and then I want pyinstaller to error out without producing a program at all, and preferably with a big honking error message that explains exactly which modules are missing from `A`. I *never* want to encounter a runtime `ImportError` in virtualenv `B`.

How can I make this happen?

(I know I'll need to add a bunch of hooks and/or exclusions to deal with the fact that e.g. `win32com` is *expected* to be missing from `A`. I'm okay with that.)

(Ideally I could even enforce that the resulting program runs the same on virtualenv `B` even if `win32com` *is* installed in `B`, i.e., the pyinstaller-generated executable wouldn't have any runtime dependencies at all. But that's just a nice-to-have, not a must-have.)

Comment: If I got that correctly, you can have a script that runs your import statements (or something similar that detects the packages) before running `pyinstaller`. If you are worried about dependencies you can [try the `Pyinstaller.utils.hooks.collect_submodules`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/hooks.html#useful-items-in-pyinstaller-utils-hooks) subroutine. Alternatively, you can inspect the [Built-time Messages](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#build-time-messages), but I think this is more complicated than it sounds.

Comment: Hi @Repiklis, can you elaborate on that (maybe-)answer? I don't understand the phrase "script that runs your import statements": which import statements are those, and how would running them in virtualenv `A` help? Pyinstaller knows which imports it cares about; I really just want pyinstaller to check that all the imports it cares about *exist* in virtualenv `A`. Re "worried about dependencies": I believe the problem of "sneaky submodule dependencies" is completely solved by adding pyinstaller hooks.

Comment: I am currently leaning toward writing my own program to parse the `pyinstaller/build/foo/warnfoo.txt` file... but wow that's a hack. I'm still holding out hope that I won't have to do that.

Comment: My idea was to collect the modules and check if they exist before running pyinstaller. The only other option I can think of (without touching the pyinstaller code) is the warning file parsing, but it's not ideal.

Comment: I looked in the `pyinstaller` manual a bit and found out that the collected modules are stored in the `Analysis.pure` list. In the spec file, after the `Analysis` command, you could parse that and see what is missing.

Comment: It's been a while @Quuxplusone, any update?